# Unique identifier in clickstream

Tags: clickstream

Is there a unique identifier for each event in clickstream. I've had a quick trawl, but I'm not sure that I'm seeing it.

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/analytics/export/analytics-data-feed/data-feed-contents/datafeeds-reference.html?lang=en